# python importing file but image not recognized

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter, import

I have created one python file with a drowdown menu. When i choose the option one, it imports another python file, with a checkbutton and a picture in a canvas. Both files and the picture are located in the same folder. The code import the file imports the canvas and the checkbutton, but I get the error saying  image "pyimage1" doesn't exist. If I run that second file alone, it does show the checkbutton and the image without errors. When Import a python file the images are not recognized anymore or am I doing something wrong? is any workaround there?

main program:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1560x750')

canvas=Canvas(root)
canvas.config(width=1000, height=1560, bg='light grey')
canvas.grid(row=1,column=3, rowspan=1550,ipadx=1300,ipady=750,sticky=NW)

def option_number(x):
    if x == "one":
        import part2

variable = StringVar()
variable.set("options")
w = OptionMenu(canvas, variable, "one", "two",command = option_number)
w.config(width=15, height=1,bg='blue')
w.place(x=400,y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

file to be imported:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1560x750')

canvas=Canvas(root)
canvas.config(width=1000, height=1560, bg='light grey')
canvas.grid(row=1,column=3, rowspan=1550,ipadx=1300,ipady=750,sticky=NW)

button = Checkbutton(canvas).place(x=170, y=230)
AND_gate=PhotoImage(file='AND.png') #set up variables for and_gate
labelimage_and = Label(canvas, image=AND_gate).place(x=200,y=200)

root.mainloop()
```

Updated code to import function:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1560x750')

canvas=Canvas(root)
canvas.config(width=1000, height=1560, bg='light grey')
canvas.grid(row=1,column=3, rowspan=1550,ipadx=1300,ipady=750,sticky=NW)

def option_number(x):
    if x == "one":
        from part1 import import_def

variable = StringVar()
variable.set("options")
w = OptionMenu(canvas, variable, "one", "two",command = option_number)
w.config(width=15, height=1,bg='blue')
w.place(x=400,y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

file where is the function to be imported:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def import_def():
    root = Toplevel()
    root.geometry('1560x750')
    canvas2 = Canvas(root)
    canvas2.config(width=1000, height=1560, bg='red')
    canvas2.grid(row=1, column=3, rowspan=1550, ipadx=1300, ipady=750, sticky=NW)

    button = Checkbutton(canvas2).place(x=170, y=230)
    AND_gate=PhotoImage(file='AND.png') #set up variables for and_gate
    labelimage_and = Label(canvas2, image=AND_gate).place(x=200,y=200)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That is because you are having two instance of `Tk()` try changing one to `Toplevel()`

Comment: Thank you, if I change the imported file to Toplevel() it works, (not if i change the "main file". However, choosing "one" it opens a new window with the program, but if I close that window and choose "one" again, it doesn't open anymore. Any way to make it keep opening when I choose "one"?

Comment: i would recommend to put everything isnide the 2nd file in a function and import the function and run that function instead

Comment: But I need it to be in a different window so I can close it when I'm done with it, but available it I want to do it again.

Comment: Ya i think its possible with what i just said

Comment: I put inside the 2nd file the checkbutton and the picture and import teh function, but when i run it, it open the window, but there is no image or checkbutton. It doesn't give me an error either

Comment: Did you forgot to `pack()` it or something?

Comment: No, I "grid" it. If I delete de def function line and run the 2nd file alone it works without problems.

Comment: can you update the Q with the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220678/discussion-between-fernando-and-cool-cloud).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way that I know on how to import files and functions within tkinter, not sure if this is the right way but take a look at the changes I made to both the files

**main.py:**

```
from tkinter import *
from function import import_def

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1560x750')

canvas=Canvas(root)
canvas.config(width=1000, height=1560, bg='light grey')
canvas.grid(row=1,column=3, rowspan=1550,ipadx=1300,ipady=750,sticky=NW)

def option_number(x):
    if x == "one":
        import_def()

variable = StringVar()
variable.set("options")
w = OptionMenu(canvas, variable, "one", "two",command = option_number)
w.config(width=15, height=1,bg='blue')
w.place(x=400,y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

**and function.py:**

```
from tkinter import *

def import_def():
    root = Toplevel()
    root.geometry('1560x750')
    canvas2 = Canvas(root)
    canvas2.config(width=1000, height=1560, bg='red')
    canvas2.grid(row=1, column=3, rowspan=1550, ipadx=1300, ipady=750, sticky=NW)

    button = Checkbutton(canvas2).place(x=170, y=230)
    AND_gate=PhotoImage(file='sad songs.jpg') #set up variables for and_gate
    labelimage_and = Label(canvas2, image=AND_gate).place(x=200,y=200)

    root.mainloop()
```

Hope it was of some help, do let me know if any doubts or errors.

Cheers